# Webcam problem in Skype

Tags: skype, webcam

Webcam doesn't work in my Skype. I click to webcam button, but webcam doesn't start. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you see a black square in the bottom right corner? This happens to me, but the person I'm calling can still see me. Go to Options and check if the webcam is working.

Comment: @function, no it doesn't work. There is black window in Options window, in Video Options section.

Comment: try this out http://askubuntu.com/questions/300060/skype-no-video-in-13-04